# Best practie to require a module within Sails.js globally?

Tags: javascript, bcrypt, sails.js

I am currently building out the Authentication piece of my Sails.js app, using `bcrypt` to hash my passwords. Everything is working well, here is a sample of the implementation thus far:

```
beforeCreate: function (values, next) {

    require('bcrypt').hash(values.password, 10, function passwordEncrypted(err, encryptedPassword) {

        if (err) return next(err);

        values.password = encryptedPassword;
        next();

    });

}
```

Now, both in my `model` and in my `controller`, I am using `require('bcrypt')` or `var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');` so I can use it within my class.

I am looking for a better practice way of defining `var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');` once and globally so that I can simply use the `bcrypt` variable whenever I need to (inside other models or controllers).

I am inclined to believe that Sails.js already has something in place for that? If not, what do you suggest the best route of implementation? In the end, I am looking for best practice.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Since [Node.js modules are cached once they are loaded for the first time](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching), reusing `require('bcrypt')` or not won't make any difference in terms of performance.

That said, if you are still up for doing it your way, you can require `bcrypt` in `config/bootstrap.js` and add it to the `sails` namespace:

```
module.exports.bootstrap = function (cb) {
  sails.bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

  //...

  cb();
}
```

After that you'll be able to use `sails.bcrypt` in your controllers or models.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this by utilizing globals

```
module.exports.globals = {
    bcrypt : require('bcrypt')
}
```

and in the application code, refer it like below

```
sails.config.globals.bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, function (err, hash) {
    if (!err) {
      sails.config.globals.logger.info('creatHash-hash-->', hash);
      return cb(null, hash);
    } else {
      return cb(err);
    }
  });
```